# $\lim_{x \to \infty } {1.0000000000001^x}/{x^{100}} = 0$

Tags: limits, infinity

I am confused as to how [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+x+approaches+infinity+of+1.0000000000001%5Ex%2Fx%5E100) got the answer to be $0$, because I am fairly sure that the answer should be infinity, can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: Yes. You're correct that it is infinity. This error is probably due to rounding and how slowly the limit approaches infinity. Remove some zeros from the numerator and it will diverge to infinity.

Comment: The answer is indeed 0, but I would imagine that wolfram gave up trying to evaluate by the time $x=10$, as it would be dividing what is still very close to 1 by a 100-digit number.

Comment: If you write this as $(1+1/10000000000000)^x/x^{100}$ W|A gives the correct limit.

Comment: @amd has the nut of it. Wolfram treats decimal numbers with fractional components as floating-point numbers with finite precision, whereas rational expressions are indeed assumed to have infinite precision.

Comment: What's L'hospital rule results?

Comment: Note that wolfram think's $\lim  1.0000000000001^x = 1$ (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+x+approaches+infinity+of+1.0000000000001%5Ex)  Now I tried to click on the step by step but as I'm not a subscriber all I could get was to apply exponents and calculate $\lim e^{\ln 1.0000000000001^x}$ and .... well yes the limit is $\infty$ but it's easy to see how computer might make a rounding error ant get $1$.

Comment: It takes $x\gt38181117481549541$ to even get $\frac{\left(1+10^{-13}\right)^x}{x^{100}}\gt1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $e^x\ge1+x$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1+10^{-13}\right)^x
&=e^{x\log\left(1+10^{-13}\right)}\\[6pt]
&=e^{\left(\left.x\log\left(1+10^{-13}\right)\middle/200\right.\right)\cdot200}\\[6pt]
&\ge\left(1+\frac{x\log\left(1+10^{-13}\right)}{200}\right)^{200}\\
&\ge x^{200}\,\left(\frac{\log\left(1+10^{-13}\right)}{200}\right)^{200}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{\left(1+10^{-13}\right)^x}{x^{100}}
\ge x^{100}\,\left(\frac{\log\left(1+10^{-13}\right)}{200}\right)^{200}\\
$$
and the limit is obviously infinite.

As mentioned in comments, the problem is most likely round-off error due to finite precision arithmetic.

As I mentioned in comments, it takes $x\gt38181117481549541$ to even get $\frac{\left(1+10^{-13}\right)^x}{x^{100}}\gt1$.

Answer (score -1):

If
$0 < c < 1$
and
$a > 0$
then

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&=\ln(\dfrac{(1+c)^x}{x^a})\\
&=x\ln(1+c)-a\ln(x)\\
&\gt xc/2-a\ln(x)
\qquad\text{since } \ln(1+c) > c/2\\
&\gt xc/2-2a\sqrt{x}
\qquad\text{since } \ln(x) < 2\sqrt{x}\\
&=\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x}c/2-2a)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$f(x) > 0$
for
$x > (4a/c)^2
$
and
$f(x) > \sqrt{x}$
for
$x > (2(2a+1)/c)^2
$.

In particular,
$f(x) \to \infty$.

These bounds, of course,
are much worse than 
the best bounds.